# RegEx to resize HTML-objects

Tags: php, html, regex, resize, size

I have absoulutely no experience with regular expressions, so I've run into a small issue.
I need to replace all `height="*"` and `width="*"`-html-tags with `height="auto"` and `width="auto"`.

What regular expression can I use to accomplish this in PHP?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this but isn't adding a style easier? 
* { height: auto; width: auto }

Comment: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) The fact that you have no experience isn't going to make it any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note that this is only true for the literal asterisk character. For wildcards you should the regex after the update.*

You don't need regular expressions for this, just two `str_replace()`

```
$html = str_replace (' height="*"', ' height="auto"', $html);
$html = str_replace (' width="*"', ' width="auto"', $html);
```

**Update**

You can use RegEx though. It requires more resources, but some rudamentary checks can be added (so for example `height="*"` won't be changed when NOT inside an element):

```
preg_replace ('/(<[^>]+ (height|width)=)"[^"]*"/i', '$1"auto"', $html);
```

Comment: @Emil Edited. I added some examples.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `*` in Emil's question is meant as a wildcard, not a literal asterisk...

Comment: @Tim You may be right. Let's wait until he replies. - In that case obviusly you can replace `\*` with `[^"]*` . . .

Comment: I had no idea str_replace worked with wildcards! Why isn't this documented anywhere..?
Thanks! :)

Comment: @Emil No, it does not work. I just misunderstood your question :) You have to use the regex pattern in my answer.